# Measuring elapsed time in C - nanoseconds - Float casting

Tags: c, floating-point

I want to measure the time duration between two events, such as capturing CPU snapshots at different points in time.
Is it necessary to do the cast to `float` here after multiplying it with `1000000000L`? Is it correct?

```c
float get_elapsed(domain_info *dom) {
    
    float temp;

    temp = (float)((dom->t2.tv_sec - dom->t1.tv_sec) * 1000000000L + (dom->t2.tv_nsec - dom->t1.tv_nsec);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What type is tv_sec?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't be using `float` for floating point types anyway.

Comment: As in prefer double if you need a floating point type.

Comment: And assuming the POSIX definition of `struct timeval` (which I *think* `t1` and `t2` are) then it's all integers with an integer results. And integer results can be implicitly converted to floating-point values (with zero as the decimals). So the explicit conversion is not needed. Or, indeed, using floating point types at all.

Comment: Alsop note that if there's a big enough difference in seconds, the multiplication can overflow. And signed integer overflow leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `struct timeval` is `tv_usec`, btw, so it's a different type.

Comment: @AllanWind I apologize, I of course meant `struct timespec` and not `struct timeval`.

Comment: Edward, please [edit] your question to at least show us the relevant structures. Even better, please create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would prefer passing two `const struct timespec *`  instead of whatever `domain_info` is.  This documents the actual data dependency, and you have a more general function useful in other contexts.

Comment: The parens don't match so you never compiled the code snippet.

Comment: See my answer: [Calculate average time between timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72873001/5382650) for the functions I use with `clock_gettime` and `struct timespec`

Comment: Please note that whether to use `float` or `double` depends on the system. Those telling you to use `double` are assuming an x86 PC or similar. But if you are using something like a Cortex M4, `double` would likely be a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

We don't know what `typedef struct {} domain_info` is, and the expression have unmatched parenthesis so it doesn't compile.  Let's assume you mean:

```
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    struct timespec t1;
    struct timespec t2;
} domain_info;

float get_elapsed(domain_info *dom){
    return (float)((dom->t2.tv_sec - dom->t1.tv_sec) * 1000000000L +(dom->t2.tv_nsec - dom->t1.tv_nsec));
}

int main(void) {
    // ...
}
```

The compiler would convert the expression to a `float` for you so you don't need the explicit cast or the `temp` variable.

On my system tv_sec is a 64 bit `long` but if it's 32 bits you only have a few seconds of delta before `(dom->t2.tv_sec - dom->t1.tv_sec)` overflows.  If it's a signed type, like on my system, this is undefined behavior.

Prefer `double` to `float` for improved [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609276/how-to-calculate-float-type-precision-and-does-it-make-sense/61614323#61614323) as you scale `tv_sec` by the factor `1000000000L` and also interested in delta in `tv_nsec`.

Comment: Re “6 to 9 significant digits”: [No.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609276/how-to-calculate-float-type-precision-and-does-it-make-sense/61614323#61614323)

Comment: @EricPostpischil How do I suggest I revise it (besides adding the link)?

Comment: (Assuming `float` is the common binary32.) “The resolution of `float` is one part in 2^23, about one part in 10^6.924” or “The resolution of `float` is less than one part in 10,000,000.” Since OP is measuring elapsed time, `float` might be fine for that—if some routine takes 3456.789 nanoseconds, `float` might be plenty for comparing it to an alternative that takes 3485.697 nanoseconds. They’ve got some integer type for the intermediate calculations, so putting the final result in `float` is not an issue for that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the write-up.  I am not sure that I fully really understand what you are telling me... my concern is you scale delta seconds by 10^9 so if the delta is say 100s that's 10^11 how many digits are accurate of the delta float?   If the resolution is ~1/10^7 then the final result is on msec granularity, right?  To me that defeats the purpose using nsec.  At least that was my thinking of suggesting `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: If `t1` and `t2` are a few nanoseconds apart, or even thousands of nanoseconds apart, you need the nanosecond resolution in the **times** so that, when you subtract them, you get an accurate **difference**. If `t1` and `t2` are many seconds apart, the nanoseconds may not matter much. Also, even if `t1` and `t2` are only a few nanoseconds apart, you need the seconds for those occasions when there is a rollover of nanoseconds to seconds between `t1` and `t2`…

Comment: … But, in any case, the final result of the subtraction is only a **duration**, and `float` may be sufficient to capture all the information OP needs about that duration. The duration is probably only a few seconds or less, or maybe even hours or less, not the many years that a time from a reference point may be, and OP may only need the first 20-some bits of that duration for their purposes. As long as the calculations to get that duration are done with little or no rounding error, it may be okay for the final result to have low precision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand your point about it being duration, and maybe I am silly but I don't trust timing based (micro) benchmark till it's in the 10 to 100s range. Just restating what I said differently (with sloppy c/math): if `(float) (delta_sec * 10^9 + delta_nsec) - delta_sec * 10^9`  only gives me `~10^-3` precision then there is no point of using nsec in the first place and I would call it a bug. I may still missing something important.

Comment: OP’s code does not have `(float) (delta_sec * 10^9 + delta_nsec) - delta_sec * 10^9`. That converts to `float` before subtracting. OP’s code subtracts the seconds, getting a difference in seconds. And it subtracts the nanoseconds, getting a different in nanoseconds. Those calculations are exact. Then it multiplies by a billion. If done in `float`, that introduces some rounding error, enough to destroy a difference that is only a few nanoseconds if there was a rollover. So that should be done in `double` or `integer` or with some other mitigation. But the final result can likely be `float`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil When you benchmark you compare multiple experiments, right?  t(exeriment1) and t(experiment2) so you compare them and you do that by subtracting one from the other (/ t(experiemtn1)).  Let's say t(exeriment1) is 100s aka 100 * 1000000000L which on my system is the float 99999997952.0 then for t2 I do t1 + delta and search for the first delta where t1 and t2 are different.  It turns that is at ~4096 ns so if your experiments aren't more than 4ms apart then you can't tell.  I conclude that float is unsuitable.  If you do the same exercise with double the resolution is 1ns.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Pushing for understanding (especially if I am wrong).

Comment: Measurement error of typical program execution time over 100 seconds is more than 4096 nanoseconds before any arithmetic is performed. Execution time fluctuates due to heat, multiprocessing demands, device interrupts, system timers, and so on. If you want to make some argument that somebody, somewhere might be measuring execution time so precisely, fine, they need more precision. That has nothing to do with my point that OP likely does not need any such precision in their final result.

Comment: @AllanWind minor unit issue, but the metric prefix "m" commonly indicates milli- or a factor of 1e-3.  hence 4096 nanoseconds is ~4microseconds, abbreviated to ~4µs, so ~0.004ms.  I'd also agree with Eric that measurement errors are going to dominate any issues caused by floating point rounding.  if I could get uncertainty down to one part in a million I'd be very happy, it's normally a few orders of magnitude bigger than that!

Comment: @SamMason I have no problem being wrong :-) If you only need microsecond precision then don't use a nanosecond source as it implies something that it's not.  When I studied physics in high school if you only measured an entity with a 2 digits of precision then the answer was 4.2 * 10^2 (or whatever) not 420.42334125425998.   What you are pushing against is my suggestion to use double instead of float so you don't unnecessarily leave precision on the floor (pun!).

Answer (score 0):

**Is `long` wide enough?**

`(dom->t2.tv_sec - dom->t1.tv_sec) * 1000000000L` is a problem when `long` and `time_t` are 32-bit.

Instead, ensure wider math.

`<stdint.h>` provides macros that form at least the desired bit width.

`(dom->t2.tv_sec - dom->t1.tv_sec) * INT64_C(1000000000)`

Now the multiplication will be at least 64-bit.

---

> Is it necessary to do the cast to `float` (?)

Usually the default FP type to use is `double`.  If desiring a FP return type, a cast quiets conversion warnings and is good practice here.

- Good to use `const` for the referenced data as it does not change by this function and so allows call code to pass a pointer to `const` data.

```
double get_elapsed(const domain_info *dom){
  return (double) (//
      (dom->t2.tv_sec - dom->t1.tv_sec) * INT64_C(1000000000) + //
      (dom->t2.tv_nsec - dom->t1.tv_nsec));
}
```

Comment: TIL `INT64_C()`.